# "such a face— ’im, yet not ’im—like a sudden..." - meaning of a sentence from a short story

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, literature

I would really appreciate some help here because I am absolutely clueless regarding the meaining of the phrase in bold (a ghost story by A. Blackwood http://algernonblackwood.org/Z-files/Deferred_Appointment.pdf):

> At length everything was ready, only the flashlight waiting to be
> turned on, when, stooping, he covered his head with the velvet cloth
> and peered through the lens— at no one! When he says “at no one,”
> however, he qualifies it thus: “There was a quick flash of brilliant
> white light and a face in the middle of it—my gracious Heaven! **But
> such a face— ’im, yet not ’im—like a sudden rushing glory of a face!**

Comment: "'im" means "him".

Answer (score 1):

I read that as **'im** being an abbreviated form of **him** and referring to someone known to the photographer.  When the photographer looked through the lens, there was no one there but when he took the picture using a flash light he saw a face that he recognised as very similar to, but not quite like, someone he knows (**`im**).

For example, you might briefly see a picture of a friend's brother's face and recognise enough features that you think of your friend and yet know it is not actually them: "him, but not him".

Comment: Thank you, and what exactly is meant by "rushing glory of a face!" Especially this "glory of a face", how that can be rephrased, please?

Comment: It's not possible to say exactly what the author intended the character to mean. Perhaps 'a brief glimpse of a glorious face'?